# Populate right side of HTML view on list click with data using EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ejs

I currently have a view that is essentially a list on the left and a results view on the right. I am using Node/EJS and I am passing in everything I need to populate the list and the results view on the right. The goal is each time I click on the list item, the results view will populate with data about that list item. I am unsure how to go about doing this part. The list is dynamically created so none of the list items have unique IDs.

My current proposals, I imagine I click on a list item, use jQuery to figure out the unique list item and somehow pass data to the right handside view? Maybe this can be done purely with CSS, build every single results view that corresponds to each list item and use Jquery to toggle CSS hide/show.

I am unsure of the best solution or if I am unaware of some tricks of jQuery/EJS, thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following example

```
<ul>
  <li id="item1" class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li id="item2" class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li id="item3" class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li id="item4" class="item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="itemDetail" id="item1Detail">
    Item 1 detail
  </div>
  <div class="itemDetail" id="item2Detail">
    Item 2 detail
  </div>
  <div class="itemDetail" id="item3Detail">
    Item 3 detail
  </div>
  <div class="itemDetail" id="item4Detail">
    Item 4 detail
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $("ul li").click(function(){
    var attr =  $(this).attr('id');
    $(".itemDetail").hide();
    $("#"+attr+"Detail").show();
  })
</script>
```

plnkr - 
https://plnkr.co/edit/PRYIWRjAkaHy51tYoPzM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, i figured id have to use unique IDs of some sort, will probably take this route